# How can I display and move images according to x,y Coordinates in OPENGL ANDROID

Tags: android, image, graphics, opengl-es, coordinates

How can I display and move images from Drawables according to x,y coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

I would say don't use straight OpenGL without knowing what you're doing, and since you're asking I'm pretty sure you aren't quite there. Of course, you're always welcome to delve into new territory, it's just it has a lot of little nuances that you'll bang your head against the desk for days not even knowing where to start diagnosing certain problems... I know I did

**1)** Maybe utilize a [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/LunarLander/index.html) instead?

**2)** Possibly jump over to [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/), Nic uses OpenGL and he handles it very well. Makes it much easier to start using more complex rendering methods.

**3)** If you're still wanting OpenGL, try looking at [these examples](http://www.opengl.org/resources/code/samples/glut_examples/examples/examples.html).

Good luck either way!